# How to plot data values on the bar chart?

Tags: r

```
newdata3 <- c(HAmort[3],HFmort[3],PNEUmort[3])
names(newdata3) <- c("Heart Attack Mortality Rate","Heart Failure Mortality Rate","Pneumonia Mortality Rate" )
barplot(newdata3,cex.names = 1,main="Mortality Rate for different illness in ST Rose Hospital",
xlab = myfinaldata$Hospital.Name[3], ylab = "Mortality Rate",ylim= range(0:20))
textxy()
```

Hi , may i know how to what code should i type inside the function textxy so that i can get something like this :

[The barplot i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpSJ3.png)

[My current barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cLBV.png)

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: note that the answer to your question is given in the **question** that is linked (as a prelude to the actual question).